# Regular expression for everything before an after forward slash

Tags: jquery, regex

I am completely new to regular expressions and have been trying to write one which gives me all the values in front of a `/` and then all the values after that `/`

For example, I have `Jquery` reading through my cells in a table which contain something like this `1 / 12`

And I am trying to grab the `1` separately and the `12` separately.

I managed to get the `1` but this is by using `slice` as well which i don't think i should use.

**This is what I have thus far:**

```
  $("#tableData tr:has(td)").each(function () {
            var cell = $(this).find("td:eq(0)").html().split(/[a-zA-Z,\s]/).join("").slice(0, -3);
            alert(cell);
            // alert(totals);

        });
```

could someone please help me with this?

I have created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fizor/79j8edfm/) of my progress

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) function like this:

```
var values = $cell.text().split(' / ');
```

> The split() method splits a String object into an array of strings by
>   separating the string into substrings.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `split` function to break your string in to an array Try this:

```
$("#tableData tr:has(td)").each(function () {
    var $cell = $(this)
    var values = $.trim($cell.text()).split(' / ');
    alert(values[0]);
    alert(values[1]);    
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/79j8edfm/1/)

Note I added the `$.trim()` as your example seemed to contain a lot of unneeded whitespace. You can remove that as required.

Comment: GOOD GRIEF! Here I have been trying to find regular expressions for the last 2 hours! :(

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use a split function on it without the need of a regular expression as follows:

```
var cell = $(this).find("td:eq(0)").html().split('/');

                    alert(cell[0]);
                    alert(cell[1]);
```

fiddle as follows:

> http://jsfiddle.net/learner420/79j8edfm/3/

in case you are doing this to learn regular expressions, then it's a different case. You can always go to

> http://www.regexr.com/

for learning regex...

Hope it helps...